# Deleting records do not reduce database size - MyISAM

Tags: mysql, mysql-backup

I have to maintain a MySQL database which use MyISAM engine. The database size is too large now and daily backup takes a lot of space.
I deleted million of records from the database but database size not decrease and backup file size is much more bigger.

Shall I use  OPTIMIZE TABLE statement or the myisamchk utility to reduce the size ?

Please advise.

Answer (score 4):

Optimize table will do this. You can easily do it in phpmyadmin.

OR

OPTIMIZE TABLE `mytable`;

Answer (score 3):

you can try OPTIMIZE TABLE cache_form;

also i think this question have similar issue to yours: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9728/mysql-table-very-large-size-although-it-doesnt-have-a-lot-of-records

Comment: Thank you. optimize command reduce database size but when backup with mysqldump, the backup file size does not decrease. Kindly advise.